# "Formal" asymptotic approximation of an integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, asymptotics, approximation

I wanted to asymptotically evaluate the following integral:
$$
\mathcal{I}(\epsilon)\equiv\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\int_{-|x|}^{|x|}dy f(y)\,\exp{\left(-\frac{|x|}{\epsilon}\right)}\,,
$$
for $\epsilon\sim0$ ($\epsilon>0$), where $f:\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}^+$, $f(y)\in C^{\infty}$, with an absolut maximum on $x_0=0$. Moreover $f(y)$ is an even function of $y$ and it normalized to one: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y)dy=1$. I wanted to know how to formally treat this integral other than naively expand $f(y)$ inside the integral:
$$
\mathcal{I}(\epsilon)\stackrel{?}{=}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\int_{-|x|}^{|x|}dy \left(f(0)+\frac{1}{2}f''(0)\,y^2\right)\,\exp{\left(-\frac{|x|}{\epsilon}\right)}+O\left(\epsilon^6\right)=4f(0)\epsilon^2+4f''(0)\epsilon^4+O\left(\epsilon^6\right)\,.
$$
I don't think this naiv expansion is formal and I wanted to know how to do it properly. Moreover it would be useful to know some good references where to start to study asymptotics of integrals. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides regular asymptotic methods, one can use symmetry and swap the order of integration to obtain $$I = 4\int_0^\infty dy \int_y^\infty f(y)\exp\left(-\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right)$$ $$ = 4\epsilon^2\int_0^\infty dt \: f(\epsilon t)\exp(-t) = 4f(0)\epsilon^2 +O(\epsilon^4)$$

We used the fact that $f$ is even to deduce that the next order correction would be $\epsilon^4$ rather than $\epsilon^3$.

Your "naive" expansion can be more rigorously justified in the final integral in terms of $t$. Swapping the integral with the summation for the Taylor series is allowed because the series is uniformly convergent on the interval of integration.

Comment: Thanks Ninad! How can you say that the series is uniformly convergent? Can you suggest some books or references on Asymptotic integration anyway? By the way thanks for the fast answer!

Comment: The Taylor series $\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{\varepsilon^{2k} t^{2k}}{(2k)!}f^{(2k)}(0)$ is only uniformly convergent on bounded intervals.

Comment: @Dispersion you are forgetting the exponential factor in the series $e^{-t}$

Comment: Oh yes that is right, I didn’t take it into account. I agree with you now.